# Accessing a control by specifying its container?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

My WinForms program uses a WebBrowser control, and it creates a new TabPage with a WebBrowser control inside whenever the NewWindow event is triggered, using the following code:

```
private void WebBrowser1_NewWindow(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {//open new window in new browser tab
        string newUrl = browser.Document.ActiveElement.GetAttribute("href");
        string pageName = "Page " + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString();
        TabPage detailsTab = new TabPage(pageName);
        Button closeTab = new Button();

        closeTab.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right);
        closeTab.Location = new Point(10, 10);
        closeTab.Text = "Close Tab";
        closeTab.Click += new EventHandler(btnCloseTab_Click);


        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(detailsTab);
        WebBrowser detailsBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        detailsBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        detailsBrowser.Navigate(newUrl);
        detailsTab.Controls.Add(detailsBrowser);
        detailsTab.Controls.Add(closeTab);
        closeTab.BringToFront();

        tabControl1.SelectedIndex = tabControl1.TabCount -1;


    }
```

So that each time a new browser tab is opened, a WebBrowser control called detailsBrowser is added to that tab. The problem is, if I need to get an HTML element from that browser, using something like:

```
HtmlElement saveButton = detailsBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("save")[0];
```

I have no idea which detailsBrowser will be used to pull that HtmlElement.

I tried using

```
tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls["detailsBrowser"]
```

instead of just referencing the browser by name, but this doesn't work and returns null when I try to get an HtmlElement from the browser.

Does anyone have a recommendation for how to specify a control using its container when multiple controls have the same name? Or is there a way to give each programmatically generated WebBrowser control a unique name?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the method I'm trying to use with the WebBrowser to select HTML elements:

```
public void addNote(string noteText)
    {

        WebBrowser currentBrowser = (WebBrowser) tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls["detailsBrowser"];

        HtmlElement showNotesButton = null;
        //var links = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
        var links = currentBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
        foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
        {
            if (link.GetAttribute("className") == "user_info_link")
            {
                showNotesButton = link;
            }
        }
        //HtmlElement noteBox = browser.Document.GetElementById("remark");
        HtmlElement noteBox = currentBrowser.Document.GetElementById("remark");

        //HtmlElement submitNote = browser.Document.GetElementById("save_note");
        HtmlElement submitNote = currentBrowser.Document.GetElementById("save_note");

        showNotesButton.InvokeMember("click");
        noteBox.Focus();
        noteBox.InnerText = noteText;
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        submitNote.InvokeMember("click");
    }
```

Comment: Can you use ```detailsBrowser .Name``` to specify some unique value to look it up later?

Comment: Is tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0] also null? I don't think you set the webbrowser control's name property to "detailsBrowser".

Comment: I guess I misspoke - the control is called detailsBrowser but I never specified a name property. I'll try this tomorrow, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context, such as the full method around the code that will be calling`HtmlElement saveButton = detailsBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("save")[0];`

Comment: I am trying to work on a solution for you, but without that context I can't be sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi Alexander, I'm trying to select text in an input field and click a save button by simulating user input. I've added more detail to the original post.